# TFS - linking Run ID to Test ID?

Tags: tfs, testcase, usage-statistics

TFS web:
I assigned all testers to test a specific suite / test cases.

I'm looking for a possibility to create a statistic / query to associate the run IDs to their test case ID.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such query to associate the run IDs to their test case ID, but you can achieve this via API.

Here is an example that get the first test run ID from a test case ID, you can refer to it:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/teamProjectCollection"));
ITestManagementService tms = tfsCollection.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
ITestManagementTeamProject teamProject = tms.GetTeamProject("teamproject");
var lastResult = teamProject.TestResults.ByTestId(tc.Id).OrderByDescending(tr => tr.DateStarted).FirstOrDefault();
var run= lastResult.GetTestRun();
Console.WriteLine(run.Id);
```